# import SVG from another svg file into HTML file

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg in the file breakdown.svg in the folder 'assets/svg'. I want to import it into my html. I don't want to include the svg file as it is over a 1000 lines. Please help me out.

Comment: Hai, you can add **svg** like -  `<svg src="assets/svg/breakdown.svg"></svg>`

Comment: It did not work for me :). Any other alternative?

Comment: Could you please give your SVG file link...

Comment: Do refine your question:

1. Do you have an SVG file as SVG tag (and its contents) inside one other (breakdown.svg) file?

2. Or do you just have breakdown.svg file located in the folder 'assets/svg' relative to your HTML page location?

When you are clear about that then we can help you.

Comment: I have an SVG file as SVG tag (and its contents) inside breakdown.svg file. I have posted my project on github at https://github.com/akashwebsite/doubt1 so you could have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

You can add SVG image like this..

```
 <object data="https://pixabay.com/get/57e7d34a4d50a414ead98c75c42137761522dfe35352744c742f7ad5.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
<img src="https://pixabay.com/get/57e7d34a4d50a414f1dc8460c6203f7d1c3fd6e54e507749762a7ed59544c5_640.png" ></object>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i have the svg in my files system. Look at the path which i have mentioned above

Comment: Just do like this -  `<object data="./assets/svg/breakdown.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
`